# How to read raw json request from POST request in Falcon

Tags: python, falconframework

How do I parse JSON request something like that?

```
{
  "location_with_names": [
    {
      "location_id": 101,
      "names": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location_id": 102,
      "names": [
        "a",
        "e"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location_id": 103,
      "names": [
        "f",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

sample code:

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    location_with_names = req.get_param_as_list('location_with_names')
    print(location_with_names)
```

`location_with_names` is None

Comment: Have you tried the [``json module``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)? After loading the JSON string it's just dicts and lists.

Comment: What is `req.get_param_as_list` supposed to return? What does the text response you are getting back look like?

Comment: [`get_param_as_list`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.get_param_as_list) is for *query string* parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to deserialize it first and then you can query it. That function you are using is for something [else entirely](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.get_param_as_list). Use the `stream` options available on the `Request` object, [bounded](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.bounded_stream) or [unbound](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.stream).

```
import json

def on_post(self, req, resp):
    raw_data = json.load(req.bounded_stream)
    location_with_names = raw_data.get('location_with_names')
    print(location_with_names)
```